# I want to render specific components on the basis of route name in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, expo

It does the job done, but when there are more than 10 components then it becomes difficult to debug the code. An effective way will be appriciated.

````
                name={route.name}
                component={
                    route.name == 'Cart'
                        ? Cart
                        : route.name == 'Checkout'
                        ? Checkout
                        : Home
                }
                options={{
                    title: route.name, //Set Header Title
                }}
            />```
````

Comment: Are you using only one navigation component to navigate between different screens? Can you also mention what kind of navigation is preferred for you as you are using react-navigation?

Comment: Can you include some more lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 5 conditions to check then using the conditional operator `?:` might be tricky.
So what I prefer to use `switch` case to check the `route` name and assign the corresponding component to `variable` and use that variable where you want to display your component.

```
let route = route.name;
let dyanamic_compoent;
switch(route){
  case "route_name":
     dyanamic_compoent = your_compoent_name;
     break;
  case "route_name":
     dyanamic_compoent = your_compoent_name;
     break;
  default:
     dyanamic_compoent = default_your_compoent_name;
}
```

Place this code inside your component as per your need. and use `dyanamic_component` further in your code.
If this is not what you want then, please let me know and add more code so that we can figure out a solution.